# What is the Jacobian in this context?

Tags: integration, jacobian

I'm looking at the proof that $\Gamma(x,y) = \Gamma(x+y)B(x,y)$:

> [image]

In the proof it is is assumed that $| J(z,t) | = z$. Why is this the case? What is $J(z,t)$?

**Attempt:** The substitution from $dudv$ in terms of $t$ and $z$ is roughly:

$$dudv = |\det(D \varphi)(t, z) | dtdz$$

though I'm not sure how to express $\varphi$.

Comment: It is just change variables $(u,v)\to (z,t)$ such that $u=zt$ and $v=z(1-t)$. The jacobian determinant is $J(z,t)=\det\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}& \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial z}& \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Jacobian matrix is $\{\{du/dz,du/dt\},\{dv/dz,dv/dt\}\}=\{\{t,z\},\{1-t,-z\}\}$. Its determinant is $-z.$ Under the substitution is $z=u+v$ and $t=\frac{u}{u+v},$ so $0\leq z<\infty,$ but the bounds for $t$ are reversed. Therefore the sign changes to $+z$ in the integral, where the bounds are in the usual order $[0,1].$

Comment: Two decent-looking answers in the comment section. Why are they not in answer posts?